# Get printf to append result to end of line

Tags: bash, printf, sh

Example:

```
Output "Checking something..."
```

Run a function

Append What the function returns to end of line.

```
Checking something...       [ OK ]
```

Comment: You can do kind of things only if your function doesn't print anything to the terminal.

Comment: Quite interesting. What's your script for?

Comment: You need to use something like `curses` to print to arbitrary locations on the screen, rather than simply printing to standard output (which is a stream, not an addressable terminal).

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
printf "Checking something...\t%s\n" "$(myFunction)"
```

Comment: That may work. Will check in a minute. Problem is, I have several functions to iterate through, each with their own starting statement. Checking something... Result, Doing something... Result, etc. So it changes each time.

Comment: that would change the behaviour of myFunction, also it assumes that myFunction is only outputting on stdout and not stderr as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo -n "Checking something..."
# do some other stuff
echo "       [OK]"
```

The `-n` prevents the normal newline...

Answer (score 0):

Okay so if you want to do this yu have to decide what the actual behavior should be.

Assuming you are doing this in a modern enough bourne shell (say bash) then,

```
#!/bin/sh

exec 5>output.log
exec 6>&1

st_echo='printf %s\n'
st_echo_n='printf %s'

## crude control over outputs, you can use getopts or better 
## way to pass flags (beyond scope of this question) 

if [ "$1" = "--silent" ] ;then
     exec 6>/dev/null
fi

if [ "$1" = "--no-log" ] ; then
     exec 5>/dev/null
fi

$st_echo_n "Checking something..." >&6

try_step_1() {
    your_step_1 arg1 arg2 
    another_combination_step
} >&5 2>&5

if try_step_1 ; then
    st_echo OK
else
    st_echo FAIL
fi
```